# Facebook Login only allow users with group id string

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, phonegap-plugins

### You cannot as of 4/23/2013 do what I'm asking. One thing you can do instead is write JS code that redirects to a certain page based off of the Group ID received from the login dialog.

---

I am making a Facebook connect/login area with the Facebook JS SDK. This area would be for people part of a specific Facebook group. I need the login to check to see if they are part if the group, and if not fail the login, and if they are then they can proceed to the next page.

Here is the code asking for permission to see their groups (and friends groups since the group is secret it requires this permission as per the Facebook documentation).

```
function login() {
            FB.login(
                     function(response) {
                     if (response.session) {
                     alert('8');
                     } else {
                     alert('9');
                     }
                     },
                     { scope: "email,user_groups,friends_groups" }
                     );
        }
```

I know according to the graph API I can call something like:

```
{
  "email": "*useremail*@gmail.com", 
  "id": "*userid*", 
  "groups": {
   "data": [
  {
    "id": "*groupid*", 
    "administrator": true, 
    "bookmark_order": 1
  }
], 
"paging": {
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/*userid*/groups?fields=id&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=*groupid*"
    }
  }
}
```

I put * around the things I replaced to hide the group id and my FB user id.

---

I can't find anything on Facebook's documentation stating if it is possible to call upon a specific Group ID for login instead of all Group ID's. Also if there is a work around anyone has that could just check if the values returned match the Group ID I need that would be acceptable as well.

I hope this is enough to work with and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible with the standard Facebook login sequence to set the login to fail if the user is not a member of a specific group. You will need to run a standard login and then (on your server) check to see if they are in the group. You don't want to do the group membership check in Javascript in the browser otherwise the login could be spoofed.

EDIT: You'll want to use the javascript API (once the user has logged in) to fetch the groups connection (as documented at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). Something like this (in your login callback):

```
var check_for_group = function(groupid, callback){
FB.api('/me/groups', function(response) {
  // process the list of groups: response is an array
  for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
    if(response[i].id == groupid){ callback(true); return }
  }
  callback(false);
});
};
```

Been a while since I dug into it so you'll have to verify that the response object is actually and array, but if you call `check_for_group()` with the id of the group you're looking for you it will be called with either a `true` (if the group you want was in the response list) or `false` (otherwise). Try something like that and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Could I possibly have it redirect to a page if they are part of the group, or redirect to a different page if they are _not_ part of the group?

I'm running this with Phonegap so I'm not to particularly worried about people spoofing the login since they can't see the HTML/JS/CSS code in the app view.

Thanks again :)

EDIT: I'll be sure to upvote you once I have acquired 15 points.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I'm extremely new to the Facebook developer scene. Could this be done through their tools or would I have to write my own custom code for it to work? Thanks again Femi!

Comment: No apologies necessary: sorry, that was supposed to be a longer comment, but I switched tabs and lost track.